# request the .war file on the remote server

Tags: java, maven, jersey, server-side

I have implemented Jersey server-side part  for my Android app. I have tested the Jersey with `POSTMAN` chrome extension with this URL:

```
http://localhost:8080/serverSide/webapi/data
```

And I am getting response.

I tested my Android app with some php file with this URL:

```
URL myUrl = new URL("http://byethost.com/index.php");
```

and I am getting response too.

Now I have exported my Jersey project as `.war file`, it has this name `serverSide.war`and put it on the remote server in the htdocs directory and I am trying to request it with this URL:

```
http://byethost.com/serverSide/webapi/data
```

from `POSTMAN` but I am getting `404 Not Found`?

Which URL do I have to use to request the `.war file` serverSide on the remote server from `POSTMAN` chrome extension?

I appreaciate any help.

Comment: by "remote server" you mean... what kind of server??

Comment: am I wrong or byethost does not support servlet deployment??

Comment: @eduyayo: normal server for database  too. I have test it with the index.php file and I could insert data into mysql datebase  butI am facing problem  with the `.war file` URL I am getting `404 not found`

Comment: The app needs to run in a servlet container. If I'm not mistaken htdocs is an Apache directory. Apache is not a Servlet container.

Comment: @eduyayo: do you have any idea which free provider support servlet deployment?

Comment: Look at heroku for easy cloud deployment

Comment: openshift, also is free of charge